# How to consider the removal of "Outliers percentage" ? What is acceptable?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis, outliers

I have a dataset with 5964 observations. It has a few columns with **20% (1201 observations)**, **12% (725 observations)**, and **5% (346 observartions)** outliers. If I remove them, it will affect my dataset. How to handle such cases?

Comment: I don't think there's any fully general advice that we can give you. Sometimes outliers represent a flaw in the data. E.g. if someone made a fat finger error when entering the data. Sometimes outliers represent something important about our data. If you graph earthquakes by amount of dollars of damage, you'll find only a very small percentage of measurable earthquakes do more than a dollar worth of damage. But should you exclude those earthquakes from an earthquake dataset? Obviously not.

Comment: @NickODell, in such a case, what should we do? Other than removing outliers. how to handle them?

Comment: Unfortunately, saying 'outliers' has no absolute meaning. What do you mean exactly ? In terms of z-scores...?

Comment: @keepAlive, it's after using IQR, not Zscore? does this answer your question?

Comment: I recommend that this question be moved to [Cross Validated](stats.stackexchange.com). The question is about statistics, not python or computer programming.

Comment: Anyway, regarding the title of the question, generally speaking, the answer is "bad".